# Lifting Robot To Lift Small Crates

Tags: design, wheeled-robot, mechanism

I am trying to design a robot to lift tote-crates and transport them around in a localized area. I want to be able to carry 3 tote-creates at a time.  This robot needs to be able to pickup the creates. I only want the robot to carry three at a time so keep is small and mobile. I was thinking of a design with a central lift that could carry the crates. What would you suggest as a simple ingenious way to create this robot?

Comment: Could you describe your idea in more detail?  Also, have you explored standard forklift designs?

Comment: Some design sketches would help users of the site help you...

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is an open-ended design question more suitable for [Robotics Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6221/asimovs-corner). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way?  Every crate has its own wheels and motor.  In other words one robot  per crate.  I bet that in some cases this is lower cost.  It certainly lowest the design complexity.

The other design is a "travel lift".  These are used on boat and lumber yards.  You would build a smaller version.  It is the shape of an inverted "U" with four wheels. It looks like an overhead crane, the kind the runs on an overhead I-bean track but the I beam is on wheels.  Then you place three lifts on you mobile I-beam track.  The robot could stores three crates, if the I-beam where longer it could store more.

You crate ned a handle that a lift can capture.  A magnet might help to initially align the parts and then close a mechanical latch.

like the one robot per crate idea as being fool proof simple.